# How to construct a mock csv within a method

Tags: java, csv

I am not too sure how to approach this problem. I have a big database with a lot of information so I want to avoid using all of the data in the development process. I was recommend to use a "fake csv" that i can put into my code. For example I want to be able to input the "fake csv" into the following method but I do not know how to go about constructing of doing this.

This is the method that the csv will be passed into

```
   List<Phone> getPhone(Reader reader) {
      CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(reader, '\t');
      HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<PhoneBook> strat = new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<PhoneBook>();
      strat.setType(PhoneBook.class);
      Map<String, String> map = Maps.newHashMap();
      map.put("Name", "firstName");
      map.put("Number", "phoneNumber");
      strat.setColumnMapping(map);

      CsvToBean<PhoneBook> csvToBean = new CsvToBean<PhoneBook>();
      List<PhoneBook> defaultPhone = csvToBean.parse(strat, csvReader);
      List<Phone> samples = Lists.newArrayList();
      for (Phone phoneBook : defaultPhone) {
         address.add(phoneBook);
      }

      return address;
   }
```

Any suggestions would help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the contents of your fake CSV in a String, then create a instance of [StringReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) on it and pass that to your method.

The code could be like:

```
...
private static final String FAKE_CSV="John\t123-456\nJane\t456-123\n";
private static final StringReader FAKE_CSV_READER = new StringReader(FAKE_CSV);
...
{
  ...
   getPhone(FAKE_CSV_READER);
  ...
}
...
```